# Logo to expand on page load

Tags: jquery

I have a question, is it possible to do this effect in jQuery:
http://www.oakhurstproperty.co.uk/

I need the logo to start smaller and expand like what is does in the link above on page load. It's just the logo part, I don't need the image above or the enter site bit.

I'm quite new to jQuery, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks guys

Comment: If you need to get familiar with jQuery then I'd recommend grabbing a comfy chair and doing some reading.  Here's a link to the only page you need to do the exact animation you ask for - http://api.jquery.com/animate/.  Once you've got some code and tried something come back and show us what you've done and we'll be able to help.  (On that page, do a search for "examples:" and you'll see an example that does exactly what you ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you out

**jQuery**

```
$('document').ready(function() 
       {
           $('#zoomimg').animate({width: "75%", height: "75%"}, 'slow');
       });
```

**html**

```
<div id="logo">
<img id="zoomimg" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" width="144" height="48" border="0" />
</div>
```

**csS**

```
#logo{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin:50px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should look at [jQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

It should be a quite easy task if you know a little about jQuery, I would reccomend reading the [Getting Started With jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery) Guide.

[Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/) is a good website, where you get some simple tasks to get you started, they also have a [jQuery track](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/jquery) where you will learn some basic things. It' won't take long, and in my experience most people learn the basics quite fast.

Comment: Thanks for responding, lots of useful links there for me to go through, that Codecademy website looks very useful!